# Geometric series sum $\sum_2^\infty e^{3-2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_2^\infty e^{3-2n}$$

The formulas for these things are so ambiguous I really have no clue on how to use them.

$$\frac {cr^M}{1-r}$$

$$\frac {1e^2}{1-\frac{1}{e}}$$

Is that a wrong application of the formula and why?

Comment: Simply: For a Geometric series, first identify the ratio (it's $e^{-2}$ here), $r$. You can always take a term and divide by the previous term to obtain it. If $|r|<1$, the series converges to the first term of the series divided by $1-r$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note $e^{3-2n}=e^3(e^{-2})^n$ so
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{3-2n}=e^3\sum_{n=2}^\infty (e^{-2})^n=e^3\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(e^{-2})^n-1-e^{-2}\right).$$
You can take it from here.

Answer (score 3):

The specific formula you want is
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
There is no ambiguity there. But to apply this formula to the problem at hand, you first need to translate it so that you are summing from 0 to $\infty$, not from 2 to $\infty$. In this case, you can obtain
$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty e^{3-2i} = e^3\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-2(i+2)}$$
from the more usefully-shaped
$$e^3\sum_{i=0}^\infty e^{-2i}$$
by multiplying every term by $e^{-4}$. This is a common trick for geometric series - by just multiplying by powers of your radix, you can change which values you are summing over.

From there it seems like you've got the right idea, though your value for $r$ is slightly wrong. (Maybe this was a typo?)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by e^-4

Comment: Just $1/e^4$. The 4 is $2\cdot2$, which I need to translate $-2i$ to $-2(i+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of a geometric series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}$$
In your case:
$$r = e^{-2},\ a = e^3$$
Just remember to subtract the first two elements..

Comment: Don't you want to start your sum with $k=0$ in your formula?

Comment: @user84413 - thanks..

Comment: Why is is -2 for the e, in the formula is claims that you raise it to M not -M

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is most helpful to write out the first few terms of the series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}e^{3-2n}=e^{-1}+e^{-3}+e^{-5}+\ldots$$

From this, it is easy to see that the initial term of the series is $a=e^{-1}$, and the common ratio is $r=e^{-2}$.  Using the formula for an infinite geometric series we have:

$$S=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-2}}=\frac{e}{e^2-1}$$

Comment: You formula is wrong, why is it backbards at the end?

Comment: It's not wrong - if you multiply both top and bottom by e^2, then you get from the second-last to the last expression. Both of them are valid answers, but the latter one is a little bit "cleaner".